# Limite máximo de uma caixa de texto - Swift

Tags: swift, mobile, iphone, apple

Boa Noite,

Tenho uma caixa de texto criada, como eu faço para definir um máximo de caracteres que pode ser escrito nela ? (ela tem que aceitar qualquer tipo  de caractere)

Answer (score 1):

Define o delegate do `UITextField` pra um objeto teu e implementa o método `textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange`.

Exemplo:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    let maxCharCount = 3

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.textField.delegate = self
    }

    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        return textField.text!.characters.count + string.characters.count <= self.maxCharCount
    }
}
```

Esse código não trata o caso do usuário colar um texto no textfield que passa do número máximo (do jeito que está, ele não vai deixar), mas já dá pra ter uma ideia de como fazer.

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode criar a sua própria caixa de texto subclassing o UITextField da seguinte forma:

```
@IBDesignable
class LimitedLengthField: UITextField {
    @IBInspectable var maxLength: Int = 3 // determine o limite máximo de characters para a sua caixa de texto
    var stringValue: String { return text ?? "" }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        keyboardType = .ASCIICapable   // escolha o teclado padrao para a sua caixa de texto
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)
        editingChanged(self)
    }
    func editingChanged(sender: UITextField) {
        sender.text = String(stringValue.characters.prefix(maxLength))
    }
}
```